What is the relation between logic and grammar?
Does anyone know where I might find set-theoretic (or broadly formal) explications of grammatical categories? I’m interested in something like what Brandom describes in "Inferential Man: An Interview with Robert Brandom" by Jeffrey J. Williams:

One of the reasons I went to Princeton to work with Lewis was the kind of mathematical grip he had on meaning. He understood the meaning of a sentence as the set of possible worlds in which it's true, and he understood the meaning of a singular term as the object in some possible world that's picked out by it. In formal semantics, that meant if he picked up Fido as an object, and Fido walks as the set of possible worlds in which it's true that Fido walks, then we now ask, "What kind of thing is the meaning of 'walks?'" Lewis would say, "That's a function from objects to sets of possible worlds, a function from objects to worlds in which they walk." But what's the meaning of an adverb like slowly? Well, "Fido walks slowly" is also a function from objects to sets of possible worlds in which they walk slowly. So "slowly" must be represented formally by functions from functions from objects to sets of possible worlds to functions from objects to sets of possible worlds.
What we notice now is that adverbs come in two flavors, attributive ones where, if something walks slowly, then it follows that it walks. But there's also others, for instance "in your imagination" as opposed to "in the kitchen." If you walk in your imagination, it doesn't follow that you walk. Now we can say exactly what the difference is between the function from objects to sets of possible worlds that is in the kitchen and in your imagination, what the semantic difference between attributive and non-attributive adverbs consists in, in set-theoretic terms of functions.

Is there anything like a grammar of English that consists in analyses of this kind, that conceives of categories and their modifications as functions or logical operations?

See Categorial grammar and Montague Semantics

Also Compositionality and Dynamic Semantics and Situations in Natural Language Semantics

Hans Kamp & Uwe Reyle, From Discourse to Logic: Introduction to Modeltheoretic Semantics of Natural Language (Springer, 1993

There are several applications of formal logic to natural languages, starting with
Categorial grammar.
Developed in the 1930s by Kazimierz Ajdukiewicz and in the 1950s by Yehoshua Bar-Hillel and Joachim Lambek: "the formalism consists of two parts: a lexicon, which assigns a set of types (also called categories) to each basic symbol, and some type inference rules, which determine how the type of a string of symbols follows from the types of the constituent symbols. "
See also Lambek systems.
And Montague Semantics introduced by the logician Richard Montague in the 1970s: "The salient points of Montague’s approach are a model theoretic semantics, a systematic relation between syntax and semantics, and a fully explicit description of a fragment of natural language."
